# Hyper-V - Not your standard V2V

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, snapshot

The main question is:

Can I perform a Virtual to Virtual Conversion from one Hyper-V Server to another Hyper-V Server?

Why I need to convert instead of a myriad of other options:

We've got a RHEL 5 server that somewhere along the way someone took a snapshot of.
The snapshot has gone unnoticed for...oh about 9 months. The snapshot is about 800gigs. 
Other than the massive snapshot everything is just running beautifully.

If a hardware/software/network layout would help in the answering just let me know.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?? Move it from one server to another (export/import functions for that)? Recover the space from the snapshot (delete snap and turn off VM, will merge forever)?

Comment: My goal is to get rid of the snapshot with minimal downtime. I'm expecting it to take about a week to 10 days to fully merge using normal snapshot merge procedures.

Comment: I've got available servers/storage to migrate to, so hardware isnt an issue.

Comment: I don't know what hardware you're running but my servers merge at about 100GB per hour. If it's possible to shutdown the VM at night once a day or week for an hour or two it should only take about 4 to 8 nights to merge it. You can interrupt a merge by starting the machine. If that's still not acceptable the export/import function should work, but will take *a while* if the VM has a lot of data on it.

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly, I can let the VM merge for an hour or two and it will actually let me restart without breaking the VM and then the next night I can start merging the snapshot again?

Comment: You got it. Easy, right? It does work in chunks, so the restart process isn't 100% efficient, but chunks are only several megabytes at a time, so it's not too bad.

Comment: get starwinds converter and do a v2v.

Comment: @Chris - Going to give it a go tonight and see what happens. Glad I #1 picked you ;)

Comment: if you do the v2v via starwinds convert it will take a hour at most.

Comment: @tonyroth - its a littler safer just letting the merge go through like chris said. If I do the conversion it looks like i'd have to go vhd to vmdk and back to vhd. Lord only knows what kind of...interesting things could happen to my data.

Comment: either way it will be infinately faster and its completely reliable.

Comment: I'd start by taking a backup first :)

Comment: You can 'clone' the virtual machine using solutions like Clonezilla. Can both be done live over the network or can be done offline saving it on external disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up just doing a backup and restore to a new VM. 
After getting everything back online we deleted the old VM and the 1TB snapshot that went with it. It took about two weeks for it to delete.